# Solution to a differential equation in a specific format

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble getting the solution that this problem is asking for. The problem is:
"Show that the general solution to the differential equation

$$x \frac{dy}{dx} = y \ln(x)$$

is $$ y = Cx^{\ln(\sqrt{x})}$$

I used separation and got:

$$ \int \frac 1y dy = \int \frac{\ln(x)}{x} dx $$

Integrating both sides I got:

$$ \ln (y) = \frac{({\ln(x)})^2}{2} +c $$

Then I raised both sides as a power of e and considered e to the power of c as my constant C and got:

$$ y = Ce^{\frac{({\ln(x)})^2}{2}}$$

Then I considered the portion containing e as:

$$ (e^{({\ln(x)})^2})^\frac 12 $$

This finally gave me :

$$ y= C\sqrt {(x^{\ln(x)})} $$

I do not know how the form in the problem was reached.

Comment: $\sqrt {(x^{\ln(x)})}=x^{\frac12\ln x}=x^{\ln\sqrt x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both expressions are equivalent to $$Ce^{(\log x)^2/2}$$

or

$$C\sqrt{e^{\log^2x}}$$

or

$$C\sqrt{x^{\log x}}$$
or

$$C{x^{\log\sqrt x}}$$or

$$C{x^{(\log x)/2}}.$$